# scanf and malloc in c

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

I want to write a program that takes two file paths and opens a file with the path.

for that I have two options or make a char path1[length] for example "char path1[100]".
or to use malloc for that when I don't know the length of the path so I can make a realloc and allocate more memory if the path is more than 100.

how I can do that with scanf to scan more than length = x?

thanks for the help I really appreciate that

Comment: You probably don't want scanf -- I posted a link to a question that will give other options.

Comment: @LouFranco well, Thanks its looks like it should help me! i appreciate that.